# phantomJS webpage timeout

Tags: phantomjs, webpage-rendering

I have set up a script to create webshots of our app. 
It runs perfectly and all is fine Until I encounter an image with a broken url :

```
 "<img src='http://testserver.our.intranet/fetch/image/373e8fd2339696e2feeb680b765d626e' />"
```

I have managed to break the script after 6 seconds using the below, Before it was just looping forever.

But, is it possible to ignore the network request (`AKA` take the image out of `DOM`) and then proceed to create the thumb without the image, (or with an injected image missing image !)

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address, output, size;

if (system.args.length < 3 || system.args.length > 5) {
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];
    output  = system.args[2];
    page.viewportSize = { width: 640, height: 640 };
    page.zoomFactor = 0.75;
    page.clipRect = { top: 10, left: 0, width: 640, height: 490 };
    try{
        page.open(address, function (status) {
            if (status !== 'success') {
                console.log('Unable to load the address!');
                phantom.exit();
            } else {
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    page.render(output);
                    phantom.exit();
                }, 200);
            }
        });    
    } finally{
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Max execution time " + Math.round(6000) + " seconds exceeded");
            phantom.exit(1);
        }, 6000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent question. We have a similar problem, except that is a bit harder to solve. We have a client's website that has custom javascript that is poorly written. It seems to be causing webkit to hang. We have a huge array of websites we want to test, but it doesn't work if a client's custom js is breaking webkit. The timer obj is a good solution but I am wondering if anyone has a diff solution. ... ?

Answer (score 62):

PhantomJS 1.9 has introduced a new setting, `resourceTimeout`, that controls how long a request can take before it gets cancelled. Along with that, there's a `onResourceTimeout` event that is triggered if/when a request times out.

Here's a code snippet illustrating all of the above:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();  
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 5000; // 5 seconds
page.onResourceTimeout = function(e) {
  console.log(e.errorCode);   // it'll probably be 408 
  console.log(e.errorString); // it'll probably be 'Network timeout on resource'
  console.log(e.url);         // the url whose request timed out
  phantom.exit(1);
};

page.open('http://...', function (status) {
...
}
```

Unfortunately those options are poorly documented right now. I had to go through GitHub [discussions](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/414) and the [PhantomJS source code](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/webpage.cpp) in order to find them out.

Comment: Is resourceTimeout supposed to terminate the phantomjs process that was invoked. Because for me, it does not. The phantomjs process just hangs indefinitely.

Comment: @Donato I think resourceTimeout only generates some event, which can be handled in `page.onResourceTimeout`

Comment: At least in version 1.9.8 resourceTimeout interrupts the process - so the PDF is corrupted, but the process doesn't hang. I also log which resource caused the issue by using page.onResourceTimeout = function(request)...

Comment: Using page.onResourceTimeout = ...; is not supported. Use page.property('onResourceTimeout', ...) instead. See the README file for more examples of page#property.