# How to download a file that comes as a reply after sending a GET form?

Tags: html, forms, download, casperjs

**Edit** : I'm trying to download .csv files. Why this script produces an empty `EURUSD.csv` (0KB) ? The link sends a GET request to `q.php` and returns a .csv file.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0")

casper.start('http://www.thebonnotgang.com/quotes/q.php?timeframe=1m&dayFrom=2011-07-01&dayTo=&symbol=EURUSD');

casper.then(function () {
    this.wait(30000);
});

casper.on('resource.received', function (resource) {
    console.log(resource.url);
    console.log(resource.stage);
    if (resource.stage !== "end") {
        console.log("resource.stage !== 'end'");
        return;
    }
    if (resource.url.indexOf('EURUSD') > 1) {
        console.log("Downloading csv file");
        this.download(resource.url, 'EURUSD_1m.csv');
    }
});

casper.run();
```

The `resource.stage == end` launches the download command but it produces only an empty file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [casperjs download file without specifying url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461096/casperjs-download-file-without-specifying-url)

Comment: well this doesn't work

Comment: well after deleting the first `if` I got it to create a .csv file in the destination folder but the file is empty (0KB).

Comment: Oh, I see it's a big file. This should be interesting: [CasperJS File Download Times Out After 30 Seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431524/casperjs-file-download-times-out-after-30-seconds)

Comment: Oh ok, so if there is no workaround it would be a big limitation to casperjs webscraping capabilities