# How to download with CasperJS when the URL is being redirected

Tags: javascript, download, phantomjs, casperjs

I've spent several days reading answers and testing and trying to figure out how to get to CasperJS to download a file when the URL is redirected.  I reproduced my problem trying to download Firefox from https://firefox.com  I get warnings:

```
[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail (HTTP 200): https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-48.0.2-SSL&os=linux64&lang=en-US
[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail (HTTP 200): https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/48.0.2/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-48.0.2.tar.bz2
```

and a 0 byte file called `?product=firefox-48.0.2-SSL&os=linux64&lang=en-US`

The second warning tells me casperjs gets the new url (both download the same zip file if you navigate to them using a browser)

What am I missing to capture the downloaded file?

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    pageSettings: {
        userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
    }
});

casper.start().thenOpen("https://firefox.com", function () {
    this.viewport(1200, 800);
});

casper.then(function () {
    this.click('li.os_linux64 a');
    this.wait(3000);
});

casper.on('resource.received', function (resource) {
    if (resource.stage !== "end") {
        return;
    }
    if (resource.url.indexOf('download') > -1) {
        this.download(resource.url, 'out/' + new String(resource.url).substring(resource.url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
    }
});

casper.run();
```

Versions:

casperjs 1.1.3
phantomjs 2.1.1

Command-line:

```
casperjs --verbose --log-level=warning --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true --web-security=no script.js
```

Comment: Maybe this isn't possible?  Downloading binaries appears to be a requested feature for phantomjs https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question.  All the examples I saw had

```
if (resource.stage !== "end") {
    return;
}
```

in the `casper.on('resource.received'...` function.  **Removing** this caused the download to succeed.  I'm not sure what it does (or now doesn't do).

NOTE: I also had to use a smaller download file for testing as there seems to be a 30 second timeout on casperjs/phantomjs resource receiving. see [CasperJS File Download Times Out After 30 Seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431524/casperjs-file-download-times-out-after-30-seconds)