# How to properly reload website in a javascript phantomJS context?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, screen-scraping, ghostdriver

The purpose of this question is to exclude any errors in my javascript code, as I am new to this language.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3015351/6060083) answer, I use the following code to reload a website in a `phantomJS` context in case the initial loading takes longer than a certain threshold:

```
var timer;                                        // Define timeout outside function
this.onLoadFinished = function(){                 // If page is loaded
    window.clearTimeout(timer);                   // Clear timeout function
    console.log("Page loaded - CLEAR timeout");   // Announce cleared timeout
    timer = window.setTimeout(function(){         // And set new timeout
        console.log("SET Timeout for page load"); // Announce set timeout
        window.location.reload();                 // Reload page
        console.log("PAGE reloaded")              // Announce reload
        }, 90000);                                // After 90 sec
    };
```

In the resulting `Ghostdriver.log`, I can see that the timeout has been set and cleared. Also, the reload is indicated.

*However, the reload doesn't happen because my script indefinitely hangs*:

```
phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
Page loaded - CLEAR timeout
SET Timeout for page load
PAGE reloaded
[INFO  - 2018-03-30T01:40:56.448Z] SessionManagerReqHand - 
      _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
[ERROR - 2018-03-30T01:37:11.140Z] RouterReqHand - 
      _handle.error - {"name":"Missing Command Parameter","message":.....[shortened]
```

**Question**:

**How to properly reload a page in case of timeout in a javascript** `phantomJS` **context?**

---

Another solution I have tried is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18837957/6060083):

```
this.settings.ressourceTimeout = 90000
this.onRessourceTimeout = function(){
    this.reload();
```

This didn't work either, for reasons summarized in great detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27417860/6060083) (in a nutshell, As of `phantomJS` 1.9.8 and its embedded `Ghostdriver`, `resourceTimeout` won't be applied by `Ghostdriver`).

Comment: `window.location.reload(true);`?

Comment: I have tried this & updated my question - the behavior is the same with window.location.reload(true)